# Python Pandas replace values by their opposite sign

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

I am trying to "clean" some data. I have values which are negative, which they cannot be. And I would like to replace all values that are negative to their corresponding positive values.

```
A    | B     | C
-1.9 | -0.2  | 'Hello'
1.2  | 0.3   | 'World'
```

I would like this to become

```
A    | B     | C
1.9  | 0.2   | 'Hello'
1.2  | 0.3   | 'World'
```

As of now I have just begun writing the replace statement

```
df.replace(df.loc[(df['A'] < 0) & (df['B'] < 0)],df * -1,inplace=True)
```

Please help me in the right direction

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just call [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html#pandas.DataFrame.abs):

```
In [349]:

df = df.abs()
df
Out[349]:
     A    B
0  1.9  0.2
1  1.2  0.3
```

Another method would be to create a boolean mask, drop the `NaN` rows, call `loc` on the index and assign the negative values:

```
df.loc[df[df<0].dropna().index] = -df
```

**EDIT**

For the situation where you have strings the following would work:

```
In [399]:

df[df.columns[df.dtypes != np.object]] = df[df.columns[df.dtypes != np.object]].abs()
df
Out[399]:
     A    B      C
0  1.9  0.2  Hello
1  1.2  0.3  World
```

Answer (score 1):

You can be use this way:

first make column as a string:

```
df['A']=df['A'].astype('str')

df['B']=df['B'].astype('str')
```

Then use replace function:

```
df['A']=df['A'].str.replace('-','')

df['B']=df['B'].str.replace('-','')
```

then make it as float data type:

```
df['A']=df['A'].astype('float')
df['B']=df['B'].astype('float')
```

I think this will be help you in this problem.