# How to replace a sign of all values with their opposite sign using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**Please read before pointing me to this thread: [Python Pandas replace values by their opposite sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299597/python-pandas-replace-values-by-their-opposite-sign)**

I have the following DataFrame:

```
A      | B
"1.9"  | "S"
"1.2"  | "H"
"1.9"  | "S"
```

I want to replace values in column A to the values with opposite sign for all rows where B is "S", so the outcome is as follows:

```
A       | B
"-1.9"  | "S"
"1.2"   | "H"
"-1.9"  | "S"
```

Unfortunately all values are String.

I don't have a problem with setting the right query and update matching values with something else:

```
data.loc[(data["B"]) == 'S', data.columns[1]] = 999
```

This will result with the following:

```
A       | B
"999"   | "S"
"1.2"   | "H"
"999"   | "S"
```

So I know how to the the right entries for updates, but I have no idea how to update the values with their opposite sign.

Comment: What does "Unfortunately all values are String." mean? Do you know that this is not helpful and want to say that you have to stick with it? Or don't you know how to cast those strings to float, multiply by -1 and (if really needed) cast back to string? Or is that not allowed?

Comment: Your problem can be solved but your question will most certainly not be useful because nearly everyone else will represent their data more sensibly.

Comment: If they are numbers and you want to treat them as numbers, why not keep them as numbers?

Comment: @SpghttCd I did ask a very specific question providing as much details as possible. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @cs95 they are string and I want them to be string. The problem is just as I described (and is already answered).

Comment: Problem is a lot of people don't know what they want. Take a look at the [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Unfortunately without further context, there's nothing more I can say about your problem, except that you will almost never ever want to represent strings as '"xyz"' (with the extra enclosing double quotes) as your data seems to indicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `np.where`

```
df['A']=np.where(df['B']=='S', '-'+df['A'], df['A'])
```

As recommended by SpghttCd

```
df['A']=np.where((df['B']=='S')&(~df.a.str.startswith('-')), '-'+df['A'], df['A'])
```

Comment: @SpghttCd, you are right. `np.where(df['B']=='S', df['A'].astype(float).mul(-1).astype(str), df['A'])` should do.

Answer (score 2):

Still using pandas .loc

```
 df.loc[df.B =='S', 'A'] = (df.A.astype(float)*-1).astype(str)
```

I'm assuming that both input and output are meant to be string values

Comment: At least exactly that assumption is still debatable here... :-)